# Anything wrong with this soapclient request?

Tags: php, xml, soap-client, webservice-client

Can anyone tell me a reason the following code shouldn't work, assuming it points to the right external files and calls the correct functions?

```
<?php

$xmlstr = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");

$wsdl = 'file.wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
    'cache_ttl'     => 86400, 
    'trace'         => true,
    'exceptions'    => true,
));

$xmlVar = new SoapVar($xmlstr, XSD_ANYXML);
$client->DoFunction($xmlstr);
```

The xml file it points to is an exact output of what i should send the server to get a response but all I get is an error 'Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception' talking about the header can't be null. Which sounds like it isn't getting the authentication details but they are all correct. Is there anything I'm obviously doing wrong here?

Comment: can you put the content of the xml file online ?

Comment: Hi Mikael, sorry I can't do that. It consists of a header with a few fields and a body with two fields. The header authenticates and the body sends some data that is either returned valid or invalid. I'm pretty sure the xml is sound as it's come from the source.